# VBA LOOP and If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to resolve this problem with help on Stack or MS Docmentation but no clue about what I do wrong.

I have a file with two different Sheets - one is called Query3 and the other is Detail ICL.

What I am trying to do is:

- If Column C from ICL = Column A Query3
- Sum Column N from ICL and Column D From Query3 and paste the result in Column W from ICL
- If not Column N from ICL = Column W from ICL.
  Please find below the code I have been strugguling with.

  ```
  Dim ICL As Worksheet
  Dim Qry3 As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow1 As Integer
  Dim LastRow2 As Integer
  Dim k As Range
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

  Set ICL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Detail ICL <current month>")
  Set Qry3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query3")

  LastRow1 = Qry3.Range("A" & Qry3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  LastRow2 = ICL.Range("C" & ICL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To LastRow2
  For j = 2 To LastRow1
  For Each k In ICL.Range("C2" & LastRow2).Cells
      If k = Qry3.Range("A2" & LastRow1).Cells Then
          ICL.Range("W" & i) = ICL.Range("N" & i) + Qry3.Range("B" & j)
              Else
              ICL.Range("W" & i) = ICL.Range("N" & i)
      End If
      Next
  Next j
  Next i
  ```

I am getting an output, but it is not what I am expecting . I did the calculations manually , to check the answer but I do not even understand where the difference come from.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show your desired output along with what you actually get - plus maybe some examples so we know what is in the cells you reference.

Comment: first there is B in your code instead of D and is there a need to introduce variable J  if LastRow1 is basicly even with LastRow2?

Comment: You messed up your loops. You are inserting values in one cell multiple times with your `For Each` loop. Check your code by putting cursor inside code and pressing F8 and watch your sheet and cell values.

Comment: Are you required to use VBA? Can't you just put the calculation in column W of ICL?

Comment: Where the construct `ICL.Range("C2" & LastRow2).Cells` is attempting to form an address, you're likely not getting what you want. If `LastRow2` were equal to 23, for example, your range address would end up as `Range("C223")`. My suggestion is to resize: `ICL.Range("C2").Resize(LastRow2-1,1)`.